# Kafka advertised listeners requirement failed in Kraft mode for Confluent Docker container

Tags: docker, scala, apache-kafka, junit

I tried to start a broker that is a controller `(KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'controller')` in my docker-compose,  but every time i get this error `The advertised.listeners config must only contain KRaft controller listeners from controller.listener.names when process.roles=controller`, after many search i found a test method in kafka code that validate listeners and it seems to me that when the broker role is a controller the advertised listeners should be empty, this is the method from kafka:

```
     @Test
  def testAdvertisedListenersDisallowedForKRaftControllerOnlyRole(): Unit = {
    val props = new Properties()
    props.put(KafkaConfig.ProcessRolesProp, "controller")
    val listeners = "PLAINTEXT://A:9092,SSL://B:9093,SASL_SSL://C:9094"
    props.put(KafkaConfig.ListenersProp, listeners)
    props.put(KafkaConfig.AdvertisedListenersProp, listeners) // explicitly setting it in KRaft
    props.put(KafkaConfig.ControllerListenerNamesProp, "PLAINTEXT,SSL")
    props.put(KafkaConfig.NodeIdProp, "2")
    props.put(KafkaConfig.QuorumVotersProp, "2@localhost:9092")
    val expectedExceptionContainsTextSuffix = " config must only contain KRaft controller listeners from controller.listener.names when process.roles=controller"
    assertBadConfigContainingMessage(props, "The advertised.listeners" + expectedExceptionContainsTextSuffix)

    // Still invalid due to extra listener if we set advertised listeners explicitly to be correct
    val correctListeners = "PLAINTEXT://A:9092,SSL://B:9093"
    props.put(KafkaConfig.AdvertisedListenersProp, correctListeners)
    assertBadConfigContainingMessage(props, "The advertised.listeners" + expectedExceptionContainsTextSuffix)

    // Still invalid due to extra listener if we allow advertised listeners to derive from listeners/controller.listener.names
    props.remove(KafkaConfig.AdvertisedListenersProp)
    assertBadConfigContainingMessage(props, "The listeners" + expectedExceptionContainsTextSuffix)

    // Valid now
    props.put(KafkaConfig.ListenersProp, correctListeners)
    KafkaConfig.fromProps(props)
  }
```

But when i remove the  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS or give it empty value i get this error:

```
Command [/usr/local/bin/dub ensure KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS] FAILED !
```

So did any one have an idea that can help me , I am new to kafka and docker world.

This is my docker-compose file :

```
  server-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.1.0-1-ubi8
    hostname: server-1
    container_name: server-1
    ports:
      - "39094:39094"
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: BROKER://server-1:9092,EXTERNAL://server-1:39094,CONTROLLER://server-1:9093
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: BROKER://server-1:9092,EXTERNAL://server-1:39094
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: BROKER
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_LISTENER_NAMES: CONTROLLER
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: CONTROLLER:PLAINTEXT,BROKER:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_PROCESS_ROLES: 'controller'
      KAFKA_NODE_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CONTROLLER_QUORUM_VOTERS: '1@server-1:9093,2@server-2:9093,3@server-3:9093'
      KAFKA_METADATA_LOG_SEGMENT_MS: 15000
      KAFKA_METADATA_MAX_RETENTION_MS: 1200000
      KAFKA_METADATA_LOG_MAX_RECORD_BYTES_BETWEEN_SNAPSHOTS: 2800
      KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: '/tmp/kraft-combined-logs'
    volumes:
      - ./command-input-files/reassign-topic-1-a.json:/tmp/reassign-topic-1-a.json
      - ./command-input-files/reassign-topic-1-b.json:/tmp/reassign-topic-1-b.json
      - ./command-input-files/reassign-topic-2-a.json:/tmp/reassign-topic-2-a.json
      - ./command-input-files/reassign-topic-2-b.json:/tmp/reassign-topic-2-b.json
      - ./scripts/update_run.sh:/tmp/update_run.sh
      - ./clusterID:/tmp/clusterID
    command: "bash -c '/tmp/update_run.sh && /etc/confluent/docker/run'"
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your question Your error there is printed by your assertion, so explain what you're trying to test here

Comment: okey, i am trying to start a broker with role 'controller' but i get that java error : The advertised.listeners config must only contain KRaft controller listeners from controller.listener.names when process.roles=controller. no matter what combination of listeners i set i got this error and when i remove the  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS i got Command [/usr/local/bin/dub ensure KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS] FAILED !. How can I set advertised listeners in this case.

Comment: Well, did you try `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=CONTROLLER://server-1:9092`? Also, you need a broker to actually have a Kafka producer/consumer

Comment: Alternatively, don't use the Confluent image - https://github.com/bitnami/containers/tree/main/bitnami/kafka#kafka-without-zookeeper-kraft

Comment: Yes  did but got the same java error. I know that i need a broker to produce/consume, but i want to start a server with only controller role, not as in confluent example with 'broker' and 'controller' roles. Thank you @OneCricketeer